# Flash Builder: Unable to Export error

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, flash-builder

I have a a few Flex Builder 3 projects (SDK 3.2/3.5) that I imported into Flash Builder 4. They run fine in debug mode (IE, Firefox, Chrome), with all the swf's and swc's appearing in the bin-debug folder. But, when I try to do an Export Release Build on the main project, I get the following error:

```
    "One or more errors were found while trying to 
build the release version. Unable to export."
```

There is no in errors in the Problems tab, and nothing appears in Console. Just have to hit ok and quit the process.

**UPDATE:** @doc_80 - I checked the log file, error caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: flex2/tools/
     oem/OEMException$CircularLibraryDependencyException
```

Will look into the .project file as suggested by @doc_80

Has anyone else seen this, or know of a fix? I looked a the adobe forum, but their solution to change linked resourses didnt help at all.

Brian

Comment: Did you check flash builder log file. It should be in \user_name\workspace\.metadata\.log in windows.  There could be some pointers in there. But usually this problem is usually in someway related to eclipse .project file.

Comment: Have you tried doing a "project -> Clean" before exporting a release build?  I'm guessing.

Comment: @doc_180 - checked the log file, there was an error all right. Posted it in the question. @Flextras - yeah, clean and regular build work ok. Going to look at the .project angle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent all day on this problem, found an answer.

It occurs if your using RSL's in any of your open projects. In my case one of the projects used by the main app was a Library project. Flex 3 SDK is missing files needed for FB4 to handle the RSL dependencies when Export Release build is invoked.

These missing files can be copied from the **flex-compiler-oem.jar** file in Flex 4 SDK to the same jar in the Flex 3 SDK.

I have put a step by step instructions on my blog:
http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/flash-builder-4-flex-3-sdk-export-release-build-error/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but the reason was desktop.ini file (Windows 7). It appeared in the sme directory with the sound files.

And in the log:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:.....\assets\ui\sounds\desktop.ini (Access is denied)

... sure this file is hidden. I've delete it manually and everything became OK!

Thanks to the posts here that helped to solve this problem.

Comment: Also had this weird issue. If anyone else has this problem, try quiting FB, go to your project folder and manually delete everything in the bin-debug folder. Worked for me.